# Having problem with specifying a valid predicate in vb.net program

Tags: vb.net, exe, predicate

I'm currently supporting an old vb.net app that I'm trying to migrate to another domain.
When running on an old domain, it works perfectly but when running the .exe in a new domain this error pops up:

> **System.ArgumentException: You must specify a valid predicate for
> filtering the results. Parameter name: predicate**    at
> System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Where(String predicate,
> ObjectParameter[] parameters)    at
> COOP_Incentive.frmEmployeeMaster.LoadDefaultData() in
> C:\Users\username\Desktop\CBVS For new_domain\COOP
> Incentive\Forms\Setup - Employee Master\frmEmployeeMaster.vb:line 78
> at COOP_Incentive.frmEmployeeMaster.frmEmployeeMaster_Load(Object
> sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\username\Desktop\CBVS For
> new_domain\COOP Incentive\Forms\Setup - Employee
> Master\frmEmployeeMaster.vb:line 329    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)    at
> WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockContentHandler.SetVisible()    at
> WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPane.set_ActiveContent(IDockContent
> value)    at
> WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockContentHandler.Activate()    at
> WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockContentHandler.Show(DockPanel
> dockPanel, DockState dockState)    at
> COOP_Incentive.frmEmployeeMaster.Show(DockPanel dockpanel) in
> C:\Users\username\Desktop\CBVS For new_domain\COOP
> Incentive\Forms\Setup - Employee Master\frmEmployeeMaster.vb:line 356
> at COOP_Incentive.frmMenu.cmdEmployeeMaster_Click(Object sender,
> EventArgs e) in C:\Users\username\Desktop\CBVS For new_domain\COOP
> Incentive\Forms\MainForms\frmMenu.vb:line 26    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
> button, Int32 clicks)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
> IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Based on the error message this is the code it is referring to:

```
cboBusinessUnit.DataSource = (From r In DefaultBusinessUnitSet.Where(filter).Execute(MergeOption.PreserveChanges) _
                           Order By r.BussinessCode _
                           Select New With {.id = r.BussinessCode, .text = r.BussinessName}).ToList()
```

This is the filter variable that is in the "Where" part:

```
Dim filter As String = String.Join(" or ", (From result In SessionUtil.AllowedEmployerCodes _
                                               Let c = " it.BussinessCode='" + result + "' " _
                                               Select c).ToArray())
```

I am not familiar with this kind of error and how do I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While checking the filter variable, it was not reflecting any data. I needed to check all the references for SessionUtil.AllowedEmployerCodes and found out that during login, it will base on what is your SID. I overlooked a table where I should have updated my SID from old domain to new domain. It did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the filter string is landing up with some things that are making it invalid. I would suggest displaying the filter value when the error you having is thrown. It could be that one of your employercodes has an apostrophe in it as an example. In that case, you would need to wrap the result with a replace e.g. replace(result,"'","''").

Comment: This should be a Comment on the OP, not an Answer.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll check the result of this query if it returns something.